# Is it possible to multiply values in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it valid in JSON to set value of key as the result of multiplaying/adding two variables/values/string+number/string+string/etc.?Is it possible?

F.e

```
{
  "string": "600*"+40
}
```

Comment: you could provide a function, I believe.  like `{"string": function(){return 600*40} }`

Comment: @ochi not if it is really JSON

Comment: @charlietfl you are correct! Strictly speaking, JSON does not allow it

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 8):

JSON isn't code. It's not JavaScript. It's just a format for writing data. It can't do anything dynamically.

If you wanted to do something like that, you'd have to do it with whatever is creating the JSON.

With JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
const jsonStr = '{ "value": 600 }'; // load your JSON from somewhere
const data = JSON.parse(jsonStr); // parse JSON
data.value *= 40; // do stuff
console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // turn back into JSON.
```

Note, if it was something like `{ "value": "600" }` where the value is a string, not a number (note the quotation marks (`""`)), you'd have to remember to `parseInt` first: `data.value = parseInt(data.value) * 40`

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. You can't multiply Strings and JSON means that it's a string representation of a Javascript Object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save it this way

```
{
    "string": "600+40"
}
```

or

```
{
    "string": "600*40"
}
```

but it will only be string. If you want to do math on it you have to convert it.